# circuit analysis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image: circuit]

I have been struggling with this circuit below since my teacher asked a question about it. 
The question is:
-Is there any current flowing in the wire in 
the middle?

The answer is *yes*.
I tried to make sure using some circuit simulators and it was right, **my question** is how can be current flowing although the voltage between the two terminals of the wire is zero since the two resistors are in parallel, and no current flows unless there is a voltage?

Comment: Take a length of wire,  to the right of resistor no. 4. Is there current flowing in the length of wire? Is there a voltage across the length of wire?

Comment: Hey do you know about wheatstone bridge rule . It states that if the ratio of resistance of two adjacent arms is equal to that of other two adjacent arms then the current will not flow in the middle wire you had shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and no current flows unless there is a voltage?

There is no voltage across any of the (ideal) wires in the circuit simulated, correct?  Yet, there is current through them.  This is fine since Ohm's law for an ideal wire is

$$V_{wire} = R_{wire} \cdot I_{wire} = 0 \cdot I_{wire} = 0\,\mathrm{V}$$

So, for an ideal wire, *there is zero volts across for any value of current through*.

> my question is how can be current flowing although the voltage between
>   the two terminals of the wire is zero

Still, I understand your puzzlement.  I can suggest one approach that may (or may not) help you see why there *must* be a current through the wire in question.

The approach is to replace the wire with an [ideal current source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source#Background) of current $I_S$ 'downward'.  Note that the current through the ideal current source is $I_S$ *regardless* of the voltage across it.

If you solve for the voltage $V_{I_S}$ across the current source (it's not too difficult if you use superposition and you *should* work it out for yourself), you'll find that

$$V_{I_S} = I_S\cdot \frac{360}{63}\,\Omega - \frac{2}{21}V_{BAT}$$

Now it's easy to see that if $I_S = 0$, the voltage across the current source is *not* zero.  You can then *conclude* that if you replace the current source with an ideal wire, which must have zero volts across, the current through must be non-zero.

You can solve for this current by setting $V_{I_S} = 0$:

$$I_{S,0} = \frac{\frac{2}{21}V_{BAT}}{\frac{360}{63}\,\Omega} =\frac{V_{BAT}}{60\,\Omega}$$

In summary, we replaced the wire with an ideal current source, solved for the voltage across it, and then solved for what the source current must be if the voltage across the source is zero.

It then follows that if the current source is replaced with an ideal wire, which has zero volts across by definition, the current through the wire must be the same as the source current calculated above for zero volts across.

Answer (score 1):

If the vertical wire in the middle were replaced by a resistor then it would be true that a voltage difference would be necessary for a current. But the defining characteristic of an ideal wire is that the ends are always at the same voltage regardless of how much current it conducts. So the fact that the ends are at the same voltage does not alter the current.

Instead, to determine the current through that wire you need to determine the current through each of the resistors. The current going down through the center wire is $I_{wire}=I_4-I_3=I_6-I_{12}$